# jQuery - Menu with nowrap in Menuitem - Menu too small

Tags: jquery, menu

How to push a jquery menu block witdh, but only the flyout block, not every block.

Wrong
[image]

Some part of "Salzburg an der schönen Donau" is outside of the border (see image). How to change the width only of the flyout menu-block.

```
[fiddle][2]
```

Comment: fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8o8sLsw1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a class for the `ul` that you want enlarge, for example:

```
...
<ul class="external_block">
```

And CSS:

```
.ui-menu .external_block { width: 300px; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tLvfot4m/